# Combining two repos for deployment with Github Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm currently looking to separate a portion of our source code to protect it from access while the main part of the project is being worked on by various developers. The portion of code that I'm looking to isolate won't be affecting the functionality of the rest of the project. Is there some way that I can keep the same file structure on the second repo and have it merge the files on push? I'm currently auto-deploying with Github actions to AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, but the problem is that they are secure or not. But that isn't your question, so one way to do it is to use artifacts to cache your isolated files before checkout into a second repository, copy your files into the second repository structure, replace old isolated files, and then run git commit all in one CI/CD, something like:

```yaml
  upload:
    name: Upload Isolated FIles
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: isolated-files
      path: isolated-files
      retention-days: 1
  deploy:
     name: Download Isolated FIles
      - name: Download
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: isolated-files
          path: isolated-files
      - name: Update Old files
        run: cd .. cp ./isolated-new /isolated-old
      - name: Commit changes
        run: |
         git config user.email "email@email.com" &&
         git config user.name "ci-bot" &&
         git remote add origin      https://oauth2:$ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/path-to-project.git &&     
         git add . &&
         git commit -m "push back from pipeline" &&
         git push origin HEAD:main -o ci.skip
```

It's going to depend on your environment, but the idea is the same.